# How do I get the return code in Java after executing a windows command line command

Tags: java

I'm doing something like this in Java right now

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 -w 100 127.0.0.1")
```

How can I read the windows exec code? I already know how to read the command line output from the command, but what if I just want the 0 or 1 telling me whether it was successful or failed?

Answer (score 8):

Use `Process.exitValue()` method. You will need to handle the exception thrown if the process has not yet exited and retry.

Or, you could use `Process.waitFor()` to wait for the process to end and it will return the process exit value also (thanks to [increment1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074041/increment1)).

Comment: process.waitFor() will return the exit value, so no need for the subsequent call to process.exitValue().

Answer (score 5):

next line of code:

```
int returnCode = p.waitFor();
```

This blocks until process is complete.  You can also use the Process.exitValue() method, if you don't want to block.  See [Java6 Process class API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Process#exitValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29)

Comment: Unless you already know for sure the process has finished, you should use waitFor() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You

```
waitFor()
```

it and then get

```
exitValue()
```

.