# How catch batch file errors in java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Question is self-explanatory. I'm working on desktop application that executes batch files. Honestly i don't know batch files nature but i searched on internet to find how to understand batch file successfuly get the end of file. If there isn't any library is it possible to add a command line to end of batch file and pass a flag to JVM? Maybe we can execute a command by Batch File that invokes listener in Java Application?

Comment: I found this solution on internet. Those guys were right. Thanks for help. http://www.javacreed.com/running-a-batch-file-with-processbuilder/

Answer (score 1):

Check the return code of the batch file.

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  REM do something here to address the error
)
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9120661

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

a common way is to use the `exit`command. You can give it a parameter, which is returned as errorlevel: `exit 1` (`0` is used as "successful", `1` as "error").

The exitcode can be any integer, which you can process (e.g. 2=file not found, 3=input missing ....)

```
if "%1"=="" exit 3      :: no input parameter
if not exist %1 exit 2  :: file not found
rem more code
exit 0                  :: successful
```